# Javascript Function Chaining

Tags: javascript, node.js, chaining

I often see function chaines like this:

```
db.find('where...')
.success(function(){...})
.error(function(error){...});
```

I'm working on validation library for my project and i wonder how can i do chaining like that.
Greetings

Answer (score 7):

Just return the object you are operating on from your function calls.

```
function MyObject(x, y) {
    var self = this;
    self.x = x;
    self.y = y;
    return {
        moveLeft: function (amt) {
            self.x -= amt;
            return self;
        },
        moveRight: function (amt) {
            self.x += amt;
            return self;
        }
    }
}
var o = MyObject(0, 0);
o.moveLeft(5).moveRight(3);
```

Comment: In a few cases you return a different object where it makes sense, _e.g._ `db.find()` might return a ResultSet kind of thing, but, yes, in general, just return `this`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring is called `Promise` which is style of programming in Javascript to deal with asynchronous functions. More information here 
http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt2-practical-use

In your specific scenario, you can use `when` for that. Here is some example code that can get you started

```
function validateUnique() {
  var deferred = when.defer();
  db.query(...query to check uniqueness here.., function(error, result){
    // this is a normal callback-style function
    if (error) {
      deferred.reject(error);
    } else {
      deferred.resolve(result);
    }
  }

  return deferred.promise(); // return a Deferred object so that others can consume
}
```

Usage

```
validateUnique().done(function(result){
  // handle result here
}, function(error){
  // handle error here
})
```

If you want to continue the chain

```
validateUnique().then(anotherValidateFunction)
                .then(yetAnotherValidateFunction)
                .done(function(result){}, function(error){})
```

P/s: The link for `when` https://github.com/cujojs/when